# get the min value from a count subquery

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I working on 2 tables in a trial database stock and sales, I am trying to find the stock item(s) that have had the least number of sales.

The sales table has the following fields: sales_id, transaction_id, stock_id, amount
The stock table has : sid, upc, name, description, amount, price
when I run the following SQL:

```
  SELECT st.name,
    COUNT( s.stock_id ) AS num_of_individual_sales
    FROM sales AS s
    JOIN stock as st
    ON st.sid = s.stock_id
    GROUP BY s.stock_id
```

I get:

```
banana  7
mars bar    4
fiery hot monster munch 2
WWII hand grenade   4
cheese toastie  2
fish paste  3
belly fluff 2
Unicorn tears   2
spag sauce  4
cooking oil 2
```

So I then try and wrap it up as a sub query:

```
SELECT ans.name, MIN(ans.num_of_individual_sales)
FROM
(

SELECT st.name,
COUNT( s.stock_id ) AS num_of_individual_sales
FROM sales AS s
JOIN stock as st
ON st.sid = s.stock_id
GROUP BY s.stock_id

) AS ans
```

The result I'm getting is

banana 2

which even with my non-functioning brain is wrong, I was expecting to get a a recordset with all the 2's (monstermuch, cheese toastie etc)

I have tried loads of different combos but this seems to give the nearest result just not the one I want...

where am I going wrong?

cheers

Zen

**UPDATE**
worked out at about the same time as Bill Karwin posted that my understanding of the MIN and MAX commands was inaccurate.

I already understood the idea of using an ORDER BY ASC and then I could have used PHP to cut off the data when the COUNT value changed but I'm kind of doing this as a learning exercise so although there may be an easier route I was hoping that it was still possible to do it via the MIN command, I think I need to do a double sub query but have got lost somewhere, this is the newest variant.

```
SELECT st.name, st.price,
s.sales_id
From stock AS st
JOIN sales AS s
ON  st.sid = s.stock_id
WHERE COUNT(s.stock_id)=(

SELECT MIN(ans.num_of_individual_sales)
FROM
(

SELECT st.name,
COUNT( s.stock_id ) AS num_of_individual_sales
FROM sales AS s
JOIN stock as st
ON st.sid = s.stock_id
GROUP BY s.stock_id

) AS ans
)GROUP BY s.stock_id
```

but I am getting an invalid group function error

Comment: Can you say what your newest query is trying to do?

Comment: oh, I see, you want the lowest number, or all those items with that lowest number if there are more than one?  updated my answer

Comment: Hi ysth thats correct, if you look at the " i get" section of the question you will see that there are multiple sales with the value 2 so I wanted all of them to be listed. Although I appriciate that there are other and better methods and in the past I have done it with PHP and multiple queries, I just wanted to try and do it via MIN so that I can fully get my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you don't need a subquery, you just need to add an `ORDER BY num_of_individual_sales` and maybe a limit if you only want, say, the 3 items with the least number of sales.

But your query is not going to include items with no sales; is that what you want?

That said, you are receiving only one answer because there is no GROUP BY in your outer query, so MIN() is finding the minimum from all the results (but name is an arbitrary one of the names).  Just adding a `GROUP BY ans.name` would fix it, but, as I said, the subquery isn't actually needed.

Update (for updated question):

You still have an unnecessary level of subquery that you can avoid with an order by and limit, and you can use grouping functions such as COUNT() in HAVING instead of WHERE (HAVING applies after grouping, not before as WHERE does), though you still need to tell the outer query what to group on to avoid it grouping all rows:

```
SELECT st.name, st.price, s.sales_id
FROM stock AS st
JOIN sales AS s
ON st.sid = s.stock_id
GROUP BY st.sid
HAVING COUNT(s.stock_id)=(
    SELECT COUNT(s.stock_id) AS num_of_individual_sales
    FROM sales AS s
    JOIN stock as st
    ON st.sid = s.stock_id
    GROUP BY s.stock_id
    ORDER BY 1
    LIMIT 1
)
```

(untested)

Comment: Didn't know about HAVING before...probably becausde I am so poor :) would still like to try it with the MIN command though, as an academic understanding rather than practical application

Comment: ok, then you want `having count=(s.stock.id)=(select min(num_of_individual_sales) from (select count(s.stock_id) as num_of_individual_sales from sales as s join stock as st on st.sid=s.stock_id group by s.stock_id) as sales_counts)`.  but IMO it just makes the query harder to understand and probably makes the server do more work.

Comment: Thats the one ysth, thank you, you are absolutely right that the other methods are better and easier to understand but doing this now when I am trying to work out how to use it correctly will also guide me in the future when not to use it ...and it may help another peep trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

In your query, the value of `name` does not necessarily come from the same row where the `MIN(num_of_individual_sales)` is found.

Consider this query:

```
SELECT ans.name, MIN(ans.num_of_individual_sales),
  MAX(ans.num_of_individual_sales)
FROM
(
  ...    
) AS ans
```

In this example, which `name` should be output? The one with the min sales or the one with the max sales? What if there are multiple different names that are tied for min or max?

Or this query:

```
SELECT ans.name, AVG(ans.num_of_individual_sales)
FROM
(
  ...    
) AS ans
```

Which `name` should be returned if there is no single row returned by the subquery that has exactly the average number of sales? Or more than one row that is the average, but with different names?

The answer to all these questions is: *non-aggregated columns return ambiguous results* if you are doing an aggregated query. When using strict mode (like in MySQL 5.7 by default), this query will cause an error.

Here's a different solution to get both the min value of sales and the name from the corresponding row:

```
SELECT ans.name, ans.num_of_individual_sales
FROM
(
  ...    
) AS ans
ORDER BY ans.num_of_individual_sales ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I would guess stock.sid is unique so there is only one stock.name in a group.  so it seems likely to me most of your answer is off point

Comment: @ysth, there are multiple names in the "group" of the outer query, because the outer query is aggregating over all the rows returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Using sub query:

```
SELECT temp1.name, temp1.sales

FROM (SELECT st.stock_name as name,
      COUNT( s.sale_stock_id ) AS sales
      FROM test_sales AS s
      JOIN test_stock as st ON st.stock_id = s.sale_stock_id
      GROUP BY s.sale_stock_id) as temp1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT st.stock_name as name,
           COUNT(s.sale_stock_id ) AS sales
           FROM test_sales AS s
           JOIN test_stock as st ON st.stock_id = s.sale_stock_id
           GROUP BY s.sale_stock_id) as temp2

ON temp1.sales > temp2.sales

WHERE temp2.sales is null
```